# Set position and 100% width of submenu

Tags: html, css

I need some help to get the correct position of the submenu and 100% width for the subelements.

The position should be right below the arrow icon. And the submenu should get the width so that all elements will be shown in just one line without linebreak.

```css
   nav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: .3em 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
   }
   section {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
      margin-left: .5em;
   }
   section > h1 {
    margin: .5em .5em 0 .5em;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .7em;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 4px;
   }
   section > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: .25em .25em 0 .25em;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    
   }
   section > ul > li {
    font-size: .5em;
    margin: .5em 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   section ul li i {
       font-size: 3em !important;
   }
   section > ul > li > ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5em;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;

   }

   .fa-sort-desc {
    font-size: 2em !important;
    color: #B4B4B4;
    margin-top: -1em;
   }
   .fa-sort-desc:hover {
    color: #555;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <nav>
   <section>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
     <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i><br>New</li>
     <li>
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i><br>
      Save<br>
      <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
      <ul>
       <li>Subelement 1</li>
       <li>Subelement 2</li>
       <li>Subelement 3</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </section>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Rules and properties added:

```
section > ul > li > ul {
  top: 3em; /* Change */
}
section > ul > li > ul > li {
  white-space: nowrap; /* Add this to avoid wrapping of text to next line */
}
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: .3em 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
}
section {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5em;
}
section > h1 {
  margin: .5em .5em 0 .5em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #555;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
section > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: .25em .25em 0 .25em;
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
section > ul > li {
  font-size: .5em;
  margin: .5em 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
section ul li i {
  font-size: 3em !important;
}
section > ul > li > ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
section > ul > li > ul > li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.fa-sort-desc {
  font-size: 2em !important;
  color: #B4B4B4;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
.fa-sort-desc:hover {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <section>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
        <br>New</li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
        <br>Save
        <br>
        <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
        <ul>
          <li>Subelement 1</li>
          <li>Subelement 2</li>
          <li>Subelement 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: But this wouldn't be a dynamic solution. I mean, if the subelements has longer / smaller keywords, it wouldn't fit anymore, right?